# GAE: remote_api and Application Default Credentials

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Since today i've been using [remote_api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api) (python) to access the datastore on GAE.

I usually do `remote_api_shell.py -s <mydomain>`.

Today I tried and it fails, the error is:

> oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The
>   Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available
>   if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment
>   variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a
>   file defining the credentials. See
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

I cannot understand why it asks me that.

the wole output is this

```
stefano@~/gc$ remote_api_shell.py -s ....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/remote_api_shell.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/remote_api_shell.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/remote_api_shell.py", line 157, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/remote_api_shell.py", line 153, in main
    appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/remote_api_shell.py", line 74, in remote_api_shell
    secure=secure)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 734, in ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth
    credentials = client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 1204, in get_application_default
    return GoogleCredentials._get_implicit_credentials()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 1194, in _get_implicit_credentials
    raise ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError(ADC_HELP_MSG)
oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to run `gcloud auth login` in the shell and give the grant again

Comment: I have been using google app engine without ever installing gcloud. Is there another way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to the Developers Console under API Manager>>Credentials (currently at `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<<<Your App Id>>>`).
2. Click on the service account, and then on a button that is labeled: "Generate new JSON Key".
3. A file will be downloaded, save it in a secure place.
4. Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to the file you saved before you run remote_api_shell.py